# Verify the following exercise

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the following exercise and I think I know how to solve it, but I need to base the development better.

Let
$$\begin{array}{lrl}L:&(0,+\infty)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\& x&\longmapsto&\displaystyle\int_{1}^{x}\dfrac{1}{t}dt\end{array}$$
a) Prove that $L$ is derivable throughout its domain and calculate its derivative

My solution:
Here, I can say that
$$\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt=\ln(x)$$
since the domain of the function is defined for $x>0$ then it is derivable for the same interval.  And using the fundamental calculation theorem, I can get the respective derivative, right?

The doubt that I have is how I can formally prove it.

b) Prove that for all $x,y \in \textrm{dom (L)}$ it is verified that
$$L(xy)=L(x)+L(y)$$
clearly it is verified, because it is a property of the logarithms; but, I want to know how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this task should show how to derive the existence of the logarithmic function.

a) By the fundamental theorem of calculus $L$ is differentiable with $L'(x)=\frac1x$ for all $x>0$. 
b) Fix $y$ and put $f(x):=L(xy)-L(x)-L(y)$. Then $f'(x)=\frac{y}{xy}-\frac1x-0=0$ for all $x$. Moreover $f(1)=L(y)-L(1)-L(y)=0$. Thus $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. So the assertion in b) holds true for all $x$ with arbitrary $y$.